# Problem with changing default NGINX 404 error page

Tags: html, nginx, webserver, http-status-code-404

So i have a problem where i simply cannot change my nginx error page (Even after setting it up in nginx website config, it still shows the default one)
My website is under cloudflare proxy if that is the problem.

I tried looking it up in the internet, basically everyone had simmilar config so i really dont know what could be broken or so. Maybe its something in the config that blocks it maybe not. I would really appreciate some help.

**Changed real creds to mysite.com, I am aware of this**

Here's the code

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;


    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/origin.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/origin.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM->
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # See https://hstspreload.org/ before uncommenting the line below.
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; preload;";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    # Custom error pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /var/www/html/error;
        internal;
    }

    error_page 403 /403.html;
    location = /403.html {
        root /var/www/html/error;
        internal;
    }
}
```